# Passing an object to client in node/express + ejs?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a pretty large object that I need to pass to a function in a client script. I have tried using JSON.stringify, but have run into a few issues with this approach - mostly performance related. Is it possible to do something like this in ejs?

```
app.get('/load', function(req, res) {
    var data = {
        layout:'interview/load',
        locals: {
            interview: '',
            data: someLargeObj
        }
    };
    res.render('load', data);
});
```

And in my client script, I would pass this object to a function like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    load(<%- data %>); // load is a function in a client script
</script>
```

When I try this I get either

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    load();
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    load([Object object]);
</script>
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is the only way.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine,  can you please tell why to use 'JSON.stringify()' at client side? as node will pass data as form of object and stringify will just convert it to string instead we need an object right? It's not working without JSON.stringify()

Comment: @Vishal-Lia — You should be using `JSON.stringify` **server-side** in the EJS code, not client-side in the `<script>` data passed to the browser.

Comment: @Vishal-Lia did you find out the answer to your question? None of the answer below tells us why we have to `JSON.stringify` when data is passed as an object in an instance. Also, why does `JSON.stringify` convert it into object when it is supposed to do the opposite?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. Your template engine is trying to create a string from your object which leads to [Object object]. If you really want to pass data like that I think you did the correct thing by stringifying the object.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(someLargeObj)`

Answer (score 92):

In Node.js:

`res.render('mytemplate', {data: myobject});`

In EJS:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var rows =<%-JSON.stringify(data)%>
</script>
```

**SECURITY NOTE** : Don't use this to render an object with user-supplied data.  It would be possible for someone like [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) to include a substring that breaks the JSON string and starts an executable  tag  or somesuch.  For instance, in Node.js this looks pretty innocent...

```
var data = {"color": client.favorite_color}
```

but could result in a client-provided script being executed in user's browsers if they enter a color such as:

```
"titanium </script><script>alert('pwnd!')</script> oxide"
```

If you need to include user-provided content, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37920555/645715 for a better answer using Base64 encoding

Comment: Could you tell me the difference between `<%-` and `<%=`?  And why no `;` at the end?

Comment: `<%= x %>` interpolates the value of x directly and `<%-x%>` also HTML-escapes it, so characters like `<` and `>` don't get eaten by the HTML parser.

Comment: In Javascript terminal semicolons are optional, but probably better to include though.

Comment: @prototype awesome bro !!! saved my day !!! ^_^ perfect answer , was trying to HTML escape from a long time...

Comment: 1 hour frustrated debugging and this was a relief for my pain! Thank you @prototype

Comment: @prototype, can you please tell why to use 'JSON.stringify()' at client side? as node will pass data as form of object and stringify will just convert it to string instead we need an object right? It's not working without JSON.stringify()

Comment: @Vishal-Lia Node has the live object, but the html page is text.  If you don't stringify, the object will be rendered as "[Object]". Using stringify allows the html page to represent the object as something the browser can parse back into a live object.

Comment: So even if it's inside <script> tag it is still HTML text. Now I got it, I thought since we use script tag the object is valid JavaScript. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh man I wish I saw this answer last night. I was about to throw my computer out the window. Thank you.

Comment: This does not seem to work when used inside an onclick event handler. Something like: `<img onclick="updateCount(<%- JSON.stringify(data) %>)" />`. The onclick function is not show in the event listener tab.

Comment: @zean_7 I suspect what is happening is that the stringified data has double quotes, e.g.  `{"basket": "red"}`  which (if not escaped) can break the syntax when embedded inside double quotes inside the HTML, e.g. `<img onclick="updateCount({"color": "red"})" />`.   Interpolating data within HTML and scripts (and especially user supplied data), gets crazy complicated to escape, and can be a source of security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using templating, then it would be much better to get the values in the template, for example whether user is signed in or not. You can get the send local data using

```
<script>
    window.user = <%- JSON.stringify(user || null) %>
</script>
```

From the server side code, you are sending user data.

```
res.render('profile', {
    user: user.loggedin,
    title: "Title of page"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Think there's a much better way when passing an object to the ejs , you dont have to deal with JSON.stringfy and JSON.parse methods, those are a little bit tricky and confusing. Instead you can use the for in loop to travel the keys of your objects, for example:

if you have an object like such hierarchy

```
{
    "index": {
        "url": "/",
        "path_to_layout": "views/index.ejs",
        "path_to_data": [
            "data/global.json",
            {
                "data/meta.json": "default"
            }
        ]
    },
    "home": {
        "url": "/home",
        "path_to_layout": "views/home/index.ejs",
        "path_to_data": [
            "data/global.json",
            {
                "data/meta.json": "home"
            }
        ]
    },
    "about": {
        "url": "/about",
        "path_to_layout": "views/default.ejs",
        "path_to_data": [
            "data/global.json",
            {
                "data/meta.json": "about"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

On the EJS side you can loop yourObject like this;

```
<% if ( locals.yourObject) { %>
  <% for(key in yourObject) { %>
    <% if(yourObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) { %>
      <div> <a class="pagelist" href="<%= yourObject[key]['subkey'] %>"><%= key %></a></div>
    <% } %>
  <% } %>
<% } %>
```

For this example [key] can take 'index','home' and 'about' values  and subkey can be any of it's children such as 'url','path_to_layout','path_to_data'

Answer (score -2):

What you have is a result like this
    [{'re': 'tg'}]

You actually need to loop it. See javascript while loop  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp

Then, render it in your front end with ejs... i can't help on that, i use hbs