# Can i pass data from node to react?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

In node (using ejs) I can usually go:

```
res.render('home', {
        data: someData
});
```

is this still possible in react? I don't want to do client-side loading (via .ajax) for all my data, rather load some initial data and pass it to react (or flux). I haven't been able to find any examples of this.

Comment: React has server-side rendering: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-server-example

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendertostring for example.

Comment: are there any that use flux as well?

Comment: Yahoo have flux examples, dehydrating on the server, hydrating on the client. https://github.com/yahoo/flux-examples/blob/master/chat/server.js

Comment: I made this React Isomoprhic Starterkit to showcase how to make the server and client work together elegantly to build an app. Check it out, it passes "context data" from Node to the browser. https://github.com/RickWong/react-isomorphic-starterkit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing an object to client in node/express + ejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151632/passing-an-object-to-client-in-node-express-ejs)

Answer (score -1):

1. If using redux you could have some initial data in your reducers as `default values`.
2. If not using redux you can have default data in `defaultProps` for each component.
3. If you need to fetch your default/initial data you could emit an `action` in `componentDidMount`.