# pass object to javascript in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

I have problem to convert back json string containing double quote to javascript object in `JSON.parse()`. Here is details below.

1. I have a object saved in variable `groupdata`in nodejs app.js

   `[{"_id":"56adb85319dec52455d11c21","fullName":"NY Metro Office 365 What New\" group","createdAt":"2015-08-25T17:03:59.000Z","stats":{"members":65}}]`
2. In my nodejs app.js code, groupdata object is passed to client as a json string.

   `function doRender() {
       res.render('groupdata', {
           'groupdata': JSON.stringify(groupdata)
       });
   }`
3. My client code tries to prevent XSS attack first by function `htmlDecode()` then `JSON.parse()` a valid json string to object.

`JSON.parse(test1)` will succeed if only the string does not contain double quote. 
`JSON.parse(test2)` will fail as error below

```
     function htmlDecode(input){  //prevent XSS attack;
         var e = document.createElement('div');
         e.innerHTML = input;
         return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
     }
     console.log('groupdata: ' + "<%= groupdata %>");
     var test1 = htmlDecode("<%= (groupdata) %>");
     console.log('test1: ' + test1);
     var test2 = htmlDecode("<%= JSON.stringify(groupdata) %>");
     console.log('test2: ' + test2);
     JSON.parse(test1);  // Succeed if only test1 value contains no double quote
     JSON.parse(test2);  // ERROR: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token _
```

The console log in client chrome browser:

```
groupdata: [{&#34;_id&#34;:&#34;56adb85319dec52455d11c21&#34;,&#34;fullName&#34;:&#34;NY Metro Office 365 What New&#34; group&#34;,&#34;createdAt&#34;:&#34;2015-08-25T17:03:59.000Z&#34;,&#34;stats&#34;:{&#34;members&#34;:65}}]
test1: [{"_id":"56adb85319dec52455d11c21","fullName":"NY Metro Office 365 What New" group","createdAt":"2015-08-25T17:03:59.000Z","stats":{"members":65}}]
test2: "[{"_id":"56adb85319dec52455d11c21","fullName":"NY Metro Office 365 What New\" group","createdAt":"2015-08-25T17:03:59.000Z","stats":{"members":65}}]"
```

Question: How can I convert json string with double quote to javascript object in this case?

Comment: You should `JSON.parse` _before_ doing anything with the data. And you should always `JSON.parse` inside `try catch` because it throws an exception if somethings goes wrong, and you do not want this to stop your server. After you parsed the data, you can `htmlDecode` the `fullName` for example.

Comment: I fully understand that `JSON.parse` should be done at first, but I also perceive that in EJS, I need to use `<script> var myVar = <%- JSON.stringify(myVar) %>; </script>` to pass `myVar` to client side javascript. However, This exposes to XSS attack and I do need to decode the string before `JSON.parse()`.  I wonder how to accomplish both requirements?

Comment: Maybe like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18106721/387573

Comment: @migg I had a look at this but it didn't work out first time. Now I tried again and it actually works! Perhaps I did something wrong originally. This is so much cleaner than manual html decoding. Thank you so much migg! I will post my result here once the code is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that EJS has its own way to htmlescape to protect from XSS attack

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var groupdata = <%- JSON.stringify(groupdata); %>
    </script>
```

This is simple and clean. Thanks to @migg again for his commenting.

Comment: I am getting `expression expected` error  while using Webstorm, however the code is running fine.