# Node.js and express + hbs - unexpected identifier when passing variable to template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a node express app, and I am attempting to pass a variable through when rendering my `index.hbs` file, like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    Hello.

    <a href="/auth/facebook">Login with Facebook</a>

    {{req}} <!-- this works fine(ish) -->

    <script>
    var request = {{req}}; // This throws an error
    console.log(request);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `{{req}}` template variable gets outputted as `[object Object]` as expected, but when attempting to pass it through via javascript, I get `Unexpected identifier` thrown in console.  I tried modifying to use triple curly braces instead of double curly braces but that didn't seem to make a difference.

What is the correct way to set template variables using javascript?

Comment: {{req}} is template syntax, not javascript syntax. Inside the script tag, normal javascript is expected and there it doesn't make sense

Comment: try var request = req instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your template engine is replacing {{req}} with only strings.

If you want to use {{req}} in your javascript tag. Using `JSON.stringify(req)` to pass in template engine as parameter and in your javascript tags using triple  "triple-stash" `{{{req}}}` to parse the string into object

About triple-stash the doc can be found 
http://handlebarsjs.com/ in HTML Escaping part

Hope it helps

Edited:

Find similar answer here
[Passing an object to client in node/express + ejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151632/passing-an-object-to-client-in-node-express-ejs)

Comment: Just what I needed to know.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I can help you

Comment: Actually, JSON.parse still doesn't appear to work in this case; a syntax error is still thrown.

Comment: I figured it out - I just needed to also use triple curly braces in the template along with JSON.stringify on the node side.

Comment: Yes you need to stringfy it from node side and in template side you parse it accordingly. Triple curly braces is using for making string without escaping value. I will update accordingly

Comment: @yueyou .  You are my hero... I've been spending hours trying to fix this silly defect . Many thx.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with EJS. I was able to pass the object from my Express server to the template by stringifying the object:

```
//express server
res.render('index', {req: JSON.stringify(data)})

//template
var request = {req}
```