# Cannot run Mapbox within ejs template

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am doing everything as in the lesson explained, and typing exactly the same code. The lesson I am  stuck on, is to use Mapbox package, to show the location of particular campground. So there is a file show.ejs, inside there are lines of codes:

```
 <script>
        const mapToken = '<%=process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN%>';
        const campground = '<%- JSON.stringify(campground) %>';
    </script>
```

And another file showPageMap.js, with lines of codes:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = mapToken;
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container ID
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12', // style URL
    center: campground.geometry.coordinates, // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 8, // starting zoom
});

 new mapboxgl.Marker()
     .setLngLat(campground.geometry.coordinates)
     .addTo(map)
```

All this I have typed as per video by Colt, by him works everything, but I got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'coordinates')
> at showPageMap.js:5:33

Please help somebody!

Tried to google, how can I fix it, but without any results!

edit:

here's how it looks on frontend:

```
<script>
const mapToken = 'TOKEN';
const campground = '{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[8.520355,47.476804]},"_id":"648c26c9e3f99b64ff16c197","title":"Oberglatt Camp","price":100,"description":"Gut gut gut","location":"Oberglatt, Switzerland","reviews":[],"images":[],"author":{"_id":"64835051f0aef1d3a60306ef","email":"tim@gmail.com","username":"tim","__v":0},"__v":0}';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with passing object to the template.

Try removing quotes from variable when passing it to the template:

```
const campground = <%- JSON.stringify(campground) %>;
```

Comment: I have already done this, but it’s not working!

Comment: can you include server side code, where you send `campground` object to the view, does it have `geometry.coordinates` property

Comment: [Object: null prototype] {
  campground: [Object: null prototype] {
    title: 'Bloomfield',
    location: 'Bloomfield, New Jersey',
    price: '32',
    description: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
  }
}
{
  title: 'Bloomfield',
  geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ -74.185423, 40.806767 ] },
  price: 32,
  description: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
  location: 'Bloomfield, New Jersey',
  reviews: [],
  _id: new ObjectId("64908488e503186b571e8af3"),
  images: [],
  author: new ObjectId("64835051f0aef1d3a60306ef"),
  __v: 0
} created a new camp, shows coordinates, but still same error

Comment: <%- JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(campground)) %> didnt work!
res.render('show', {campground: "<WHAT'S HERE>"}); could u please tell, where should I type this, somewhere in the show.ejs or showPageMap.js or elsewhere?

Comment: on the server/route, part of the code where you render `show.ejs`, you need to pass it that object.. not sure what you're showing, it looks like two objects, and first doesn't have `coordinates`.. you need to add more details, no point in guessing.. see: [Passing an object to client in node/express + ejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151632/passing-an-object-to-client-in-node-express-ejs)

Comment: module.exports.showCampground = async (req, res,) => {
    const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate({
        path: 'reviews',
        populate: {
            path: 'author'
        }
    }).populate('author');
    if (!campground) {
        req.flash('error', 'Cannot find that campground!');
        return res.redirect('/campgrounds');
    }
    res.render('campgrounds/show', { campground });
} That one?

Comment: yes. looks good, try logging  `campground.geometry`, make sure that property is present, and also you can try hardcoding the object: `res.render('campgrounds/show', {campground: {geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [-74.185423, 40.806767] } } });` and see if it renders in the view, and if it does, then you got corrupted data.. that's all I can think off

Comment: res.render('campgrounds/show', { campground: { geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates } } }); I hardcoded like this, and got this error: 
coordinates is not defined
ReferenceError: coordinates is not defined at module.exports.showCampground

Comment: well, you didn't include coordinates property, try _exactly_ like above: `res.render('campgrounds/show', {campground: {geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [-74.185423, 40.806767] } } });`. also, it's more important to log `campground` when you get it from the database and make sure it has all the required properties, because above you showed two objects, one didn't have all the properties...

Comment: TypeError: C:\Users\jacks\Desktop\TestCamp\views\campgrounds\show.ejs:9 7| <div id="campgroundCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 8| <div class="carousel-inner"> >> 9| <% campground.images.forEach((img, i)=> { %> 10| <div class="carousel-item <%= i === 0 ? 'active' : ''%>"> 11| <img src="<%= img.url%>" class="d-block w-100" alt=""> 12| </div> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') at eval    this is what i get, when i type exactly like above.

Comment: because you didn't hardcode `images` property.. remove that part of the code for now, the point is to make sure that the code you showed in you question works, so that you can debug further

Comment: So I have changed code a little bit: 
    <script>
        const mapToken = '<%=process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN%>';
        const campgroundGeo = '<%- JSON.stringify(campground.geometry) %>'; <----
    </script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = mapToken;
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container ID
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12', // style URL
    center: campgroundGeo.coordinates, // starting position [lng, lat] <----
    zoom: 3, // starting zoom
});

new mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat(campgroundGeo.coordinates) <----
    .addTo(map)

Comment: This what I get, if console.log
{
  geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 8.520355, 47.476804 ] },
  _id: new ObjectId("648c26c9e3f99b64ff16c197"),
  title: 'Oberglatt Camp',
  price: 100,
  description: 'Gut gut gut',
  location: 'Oberglatt, Switzerland',
  reviews: [],
  images: [],
  author: {
    _id: new ObjectId("64835051f0aef1d3a60306ef"),
    email: 'tim@gmail.com',
    username: 'tim',
    __v: 0
  },
  __v: 0
}

Comment: And error Uncaught Error: `LngLatLike` argument must be specified as a LngLat instance, an object {lng: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, an object {lon: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, or an array of [<lng>, <lat>]
    at ru.convert (lng_lat.js:163:15)
    at on.setLngLat (marker.js:292:31)
    at showPageMap.js:10:6

Comment: it's `const campgroundGeo = <%- JSON.stringify(campground.geometry) %>` as already pointed out.. don't leave every debug attempt in the comments before you tried all the suggestions, and all the relevant information should be in your question

Comment: Ok, I am completely new here, i will do my best! could you help me with that error?

Comment: const campgroundGeo = <%=JSON.stringify(campground.geometry.coordinates) %> that works for me, than just pass campgroundGeo to lnglat, thanks for support and your time!